# Submiting Form that use ng-repeat in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having some trouble with angularJS, when i sumbit the data it's always empty , I'm displaying that data using ng-repeat like below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateTasks", "Revision", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSaveSuccess" @*, OnBegin="ValidateForm"*@} ,  new { @id = "participantForm", @class = "form-validation-1" }))
{
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div id="idiv">
<table id="tbl" name="tbl" ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1" style="color:black">
   <tr>
      <th> Task</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.Question" class="form-control"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

  <input class="btn m-r-5" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

and this is my controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateTasks(object tasks)
        {
var tsk = tasks ;
            return Json(new { isError ="" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

but the object tasks is always empty , what did i miss ?

Comment: 1.ng-repeat should be written with the line which you want to repeat, which in your case is `<td>`
Second thing is try giving different ids to each textbox(u can use $index) of angular).Another thing is ng-model would never work like MVC model Binder works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,
First get All data in a object,then use ng-repeat for display the data/information in html form.

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code. Let's start one by one.

- Use angularjs $http service to post data to your server. It makes little sense to use angularjs and post data with razor.
- Create a model with attributes that match the ones you're posting from the client and use it in the controller action instead of "object" type. MVC Model Binder automatically maps the fields and populates them.

About your actual problem, it is because you have not associated a name attribute with your input fields. Try something like this and let me know if you need further pointers :)

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div id="idiv">
<table id="tbl" name="tbl" ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1" style="color:black">
   <tr>
      <th> Task</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td ng-repeat="x in records">
         <input name="{{x.Question}}" type="text" ng-model="x.Question" class="form-control">
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>

  <input class="btn m-r-5" type="submit" value="Save" />
```